# How to change Sonarqube rule priority for default JAVA rules?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.2

I need to downgrade/upgrade some of the priority levels of default SQ rules.

For Eg: The duplicated block of code rule , seems to be false positive in our scenario so we need to downgrade for Major to Info/Minor.

The Hardcoded password rule needs to be a blocker for us.

I couldn't find any documentation on the same. can the rule priorities be changed, if so how?

Note:I'm using SQ 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you have to edit your quality profiles, see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles